# How to share posts in Wordpress Multisite?

Tags: multisite

It's the first time I am using the multisite option. I must be searching for the wrong terms, because I can't find the answer to what I think it's a simple problem...

I have 3 sites.

1. Group Landing site
2. Group 1 site
3. Group 2 site

Essentially, Group 1 and Group 2 will have separate contents. However the Group Landing site will have content from both. I would rather not have the user enter the content twice. Using Multisite, is there a way for me to poll content from Group 1 and Group 2, and display it in Group Landing?

If not, what's a better option to share content between sites?

Comment: what does sharing includes, images, text tags, seo? And what happens when the source is editted or deleted?

Comment: I want to poll content. That means, that I want to be able to run a query and get information from other posts and pages and display on the front end. I am not looking to duplicate content on the backend, or to share content on the backend. So, if the source is deleted than nothing will show on the front-end.

Comment: then please edit the question to reflect that.

Comment: That's exactly what my questions says... "is there a way for me to poll content from Group 1 and Group 2, and display it in Group Landing?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the function [`switch_to_blog`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/switch_to_blog)

Example:

```
switch_to_blog( $site_id );
$post = get_post( $post_id );
restore_current_blog();
```

It should do exactly what you need. After switching you can use a custom query to get the relevant information

Comment: As increase, after switch get your data, like post and then use the function `restore_current_blog()`.

Comment: Doesn't this all you to query content only from a specific site? What if I want to query all posts of the same type across all sites?

Answer (score 0):

Use the Network Posts Extended Plugin. It let's you choose which posts (all post types including pages and custom post types) that you'd like. Plus works well with woocommerce and advanced custom fields plugin.